# Разбить строку на массив: разделитель - новая строка

Tags: массивы, php, строки

разбить строку на массив разделитель новая строка

Есть строка вида:

```
    [img_url_list] => /getattachment/Каталог/Аксессуары-для-накамерных-вспышек/Софтбоксы-для-накамерных-вспышек/СОФТБОКС-ДЛЯ-НАКАМЕРНЫХ-ФОТОВСПЫШЕК-FANCIER-SB1009/fancier_softboks_sb1009_40x40sm_dlya_nakamernih_fotovspishek_2.jpg.aspx
/getattachment/Каталог/Аксессуары-для-накамерных-вспышек/Софтбоксы-для-накамерных-вспышек/СОФТБОКС-ДЛЯ-НАКАМЕРНЫХ-ФОТОВСПЫШЕК-FANCIER-SB1009/fancier_softboks_sb1009_40x40sm_dlya_nakamernih_fotovspishek_3.jpg.aspx
/getattachment/Каталог/Аксессуары-для-накамерных-вспышек/Софтбоксы-для-накамерных-вспышек/СОФТБОКС-ДЛЯ-НАКАМЕРНЫХ-ФОТОВСПЫШЕК-FANCIER-SB1009/fancier_softboks_sb1009_40x40sm_dlya_nakamernih_fotovspishek_4.jpg.aspx
```

Разбиваю ее на массив функцией:

```
$imgarray = explode("/n", $array["img_url_list"]);
```

Но получаю только:

```
Array
(
    [0] => /getattachment/Каталог/Генераторныи-свет/Аксессуары/Адаптер-Jinbei-EN-760-Converter-for-Car-battery/jinbei-energon.jpg.aspx
/getattachment/Каталог/Генераторныи-свет/Аксессуары/Адаптер-Jinbei-EN-760-Converter-for-Car-battery/jinbei-energonports.jpg.aspx
/getattachment/Каталог/Генераторныи-свет/Аксессуары/Адаптер-Jinbei-EN-760-Converter-for-Car-battery/jinbei-energonsetup.jpg.aspx
/getattachment/Каталог/Генераторныи-свет/Аксессуары/Адаптер-Jinbei-EN-760-Converter-for-Car-battery/jinbei-energontop.jpg.aspx
)
```

Как правильно сделать ее массивом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

не /n, а \n только

Comment: @Fike, тогда уж лучше использовать константу **[PHP_EOL][1]**

    $imgarray = explode(PHP_EOL, $array["img_url_list"]);

  [1]: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/reserved.constants.php

Comment: @VenZell, если отвечать глобально, то нет. Нет гарантий, что текст собирался с значением `PHP_EOL` в качестве разделителя.

Answer (score 1):

"\r\n" вместо "/n"